# Modify App Delegate to Use Tabbed View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

Im learning IOS progrmaming right now and have no idea how to set up a tabbed view controller from my two current view controllers. Can someone help. Let me know if you need more information. I only want two tabs one for each of these UINAvigationControllers.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /*
     This is how you set up with movies at root
     */
    NSString *moviesURLString = @"irrelevantURL";
    self.movieDataSource = [[MoviesDataSource alloc] initWithMoviesAtURLString:moviesURLString];
    MoviesTableViewController *mvc = [[MoviesTableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *mnc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mvc];
    // [self.window setRootViewController:mnc];

    /*
     This is how you set up with theaters at root
     */
    NSString *theatersURLString = @"irrelevantURL";
    self.movieTheaterDataSource = [[MovieTheaterDataSource alloc] initWithMovieTheatersAtURLString:theatersURLString];
    MovieTheaterTableViewController *mtvc = [[MovieTheaterTableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *mtnc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mtvc];
    // [self.window setRootViewController:mtnc];
    /*
     Trying to set up tabbed views
     */
    UITabBar *tabbedView = [[UITabBar alloc] init];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is as below.
 * make UIWindow class instance.
 * make UITabBarController class instance and assign two UINavigationControllers to UITabBarController instance viewControllers property.

So, the code which you should write is as below.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    /*
     This is how you set up with movies at root
     */
    NSString *moviesURLString = @"irrelevantURL";
    self.movieDataSource = [[MoviesDataSource alloc] initWithMoviesAtURLString:moviesURLString];
    MoviesTableViewController *mvc = [[MoviesTableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *mnc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mvc];

    /*
     This is how you set up with theaters at root
     */
    NSString *theatersURLString = @"irrelevantURL";
    self.movieTheaterDataSource = [[MovieTheaterDataSource alloc] initWithMovieTheatersAtURLString:theatersURLString];
    MovieTheaterTableViewController *mtvc = [[MovieTheaterTableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *mtnc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mtvc];

    //set up tabBarController
    UITabBarController *tabvc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabvc.viewControllers = @[mnc, mtnc];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabvc;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Correct however I needed to initialize the tabvc like so `tabvc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mnc, mtnc, nil];`  if you change it or explain why the `tabvc.viewControllers = [mnc, mtnc];` has the error "Expected Identifier" ill mark it correct

Comment: I'm so sorry.
I typo that array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set this up in the main.storyboard?

If you do you should't need to use the app delegate.